# How to make a python version as default version in ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

Am using ubuntu 20.04 ,I have two versions of python installed  3.8.5 and 3.8.2. How to make Python 3.8.2 as the default version for python3

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.8.5

$ python3.8 -V
Python 3.8.2
```

Comment: Maybe go on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: You either could use virtual environments or [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage multiple versions of Python.